# "No such theme PatternSkinTheme" error message

Tags: foswiki

I have installed foswiki and made basic configuration changes (enabled/disabled plugins, change of patch etc.). Since that time I can see red error message on every window "***No such theme PatternSkinTheme***" and the banner with Foswiki's logo, "*Jump*" and "*Search*" textboxes is located in the end of the pages.

[image: Foswiki screenshot]

I tried to revert the configuration back, however the situation still persists. Does somebody know where might be the issue?

Thank you

Comment: When I disable all plugins, I can see that only `%JQTHEME{"PatternSkinTheme"}%` message. Might be helpful ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there were 2 issues:
First issue was related with error message and the second with incorrect position of the banner.

#### First issue

The message disappeared after adding in /path/to/foswiki/lib/LocalSite.cfg following lines:

`$Foswiki::cfg{JQueryPlugin}{Themes}{PatternSkinTheme}{Enabled} = 1;`
`$Foswiki::cfg{JQueryPlugin}{Themes}{PatternSkinTheme}{Url} = $Foswiki::cfg{PubUrlPath}/$Foswiki::cfg{SystemWebName}/PatternSkinTheme/jquery-ui.css';`

#### Second issue

Update in file /path/to/foswiki/templates/foswiki.pattern.tmpl structure of the webpage. I removed `%TMPL:P{"topbar"}%` from the definition like this

`...
</div>%TMPL:P{"endsidebarwrapper"}%%TMPL:P{"topbar"}%%TMPL:P{"bottombar"}%
...`

and place it to

`...
%TMPL:DEF{"main"}%<div class="foswikiPage"><div id="patternScreen">
<div id="patternPageShadow">`**%TMPL:P{"topbar"}%**`%TMPL:P{"metanavigation"}%
<div id="patternPage">
...`